# What is the purpose behind "On hold"

Tags: discussion

This is why I am often discouraged from posting on StackOverflow. I have spent the past 3 days trying to solve a problem and I posted on SO and the question was put [on-hold]. I had received a few comments that were helpful, but SO decided to put the question on hold right before my question could be resolved.

In my opinion the question is clear, but that's besides the point. I feel that people are constantly searching for content to moderate over as a way to vent their negativity with a power-trip over others.

**Bottom line**: Why does it matter if a question is unclear? I was getting productive help from other's comments before this happened. Furthermore, who cares? Shouldn't SO be a place that any good-intention question potentially helpful to others be allowed? I mean if you don't like a question, fine, down vote it, but don't try to take away my ability to learn from others in the process.

Comment: It is an interim period to allow the OP to fix the question so it can be reopened.  If left unattended, it will likely be deleted.  BTW, "good intentions" are not enough - there has to some merit to it, such as usefullness to others, complexity and of course, be well written.  If it is *unclear* how can anyone answer?

Comment: People don't search for content to moderate, the content to moderate comes to them.

Comment: @Plutonix- the proof is in the pudding. If my question was unclear how could I receive helpful advice from others?

Comment: @TheJavaBeast Simple: make it clearer.

Comment: @TheJavaBeast "I wonder why my question isn't getting answers?" -> "Oh, it's unclear what I'm asking. That makes sense."

Comment: @hichris123- I did and the question was never re-opened. Not to mention, even if it was re-opened a few days later it wouldn't have received many views at that point

Comment: @Emrakul- my question was getting answers. That's the point here.

Comment: Helpful comments are not answers.  Many will avoid answering such questions with actual answers because murky questions have a habit of becoming XY problems.  When clarified, the previously posted answers are wrong and get DVed by those who havent witnessed the whole sordid affair of teasing out pertinent details from the OP.  (If Jon Skeet thinks it unclear. chances are it is unclear).

Comment: It may be helpful to review the [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) FAQ post. [Robert Cartaino's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115/231078): "**In contrast, Stack Exchange encourages *specific* questions** that have a *specific*, canonical answers. A question is asked and
respondents weigh in with a **carefully-thought-out response** which
is then vetted through voting and wiki-editing (improving on the
answer)."

Comment: The actual question (which it took *way* too long to get to, I was afraid there was no question at all for a while); is ok, but could be *too broad*. "How do I use eclipse and run/compile code on Linux?" is going to have issues over "How do I fix line endings generated by Eclipse?". You could have gotten the "Unclear" designation just due to the wall of text preceding the question, but it might have gotten closed as "too broad" anyways.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for the helpful advice. Perhaps the "wall of text" was the reason, but the only reason it was there was to provide all relevant information to prevent exactly what Louis eludes too: an answer not relevant to the OP question

Comment: @TheJavaBeast I'm not saying don't include it (though there was a *bit* more backstory than necessary) but you should have *started* the post with your question, then provided a more succinct set of background information. I was literally thinking halfway through reading your post "There is no question here... what is he asking...". Not really fair, but such questions could net a close vote before the reader gets to the end; especially on *really* long posts.

Comment: if I only had a penny for every helpful SO question I have found that was closed for either this or "too subjective" reasons... my point is perhaps some loose sight that we (in my opinion) are here to help each other solve problems, rather then be sticklers on the small stuff often(but not always) irrelevant

Comment: @BradleyDotNET- point taken. thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Who cares? People who answer unclear question might care, just to name some people who have a stake in the process.

The issue with unclear questions is that people are going to guess what the problem might be. Then the OP will come back and tell the answerers that they guessed wrong, and perhaps update the question. So the people who first answered wasted their time, sometimes substantially. I've seen really polished answers be deleted because their authors guessed wrong. And this is not a case where the question can be rolled back to what it was (which *can* be done with questions that are chameleon questions but were otherwise clear from the get go).

**This is aggravating for all concerned, including the OP.** Those who tried to help wasted their time. The OP is in the unenviable position of having to tell people they guessed wrong, which is quite awkward. In the meantime people who *could* have helped, passed because they had nothing to add to the good answers already submitted.

Everybody loses.

If the unclear question is closed fast enough, the submission of well-meant but useless answers can be prevented, and when the question is reopened, it can get answers that actually solve the real problem.

Comment: This makes sense, and I agree. I guess for me it just goes back to I believe my question was clear and all who commented understood the problem and gave helpful advice.