# What's the purpose of closing questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I don't understand the point of **actively preventing** people from answering questions. What good does it do? I've often experienced the frustration of spending a few minutes writing an answer to a question that got closed right before I could post my answer. This does *not* have a positive effect on my morale.

The closest thing to an answer I could find is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276530/1222951). Quote:

```
 the submission of well-meant but useless answers can be prevented
```

Is posting well-meant answers something that needs to be prevented? If I believe I understand the question, sometimes I would rather post a *potentially* useless, or incomplete, answer, than post no answer at all. I'm here to *help* other people, and I cannot do that by *not answering*.

Comment: I can't say I didn't expect the downvotes, but might I at least know the reason? Can't improve it if I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Reasons for voting on meta are difficult to predict. Possibly people disagree with your underlying premise that closing questions is somehow a negative thing, when it's an almost entirely positive thing for the site

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What good does it do?

It means that people that ask low quality or bad questions have an incentive to improve the posts, if they want an answer.

It keeps quality up and rubbish out of the site (there are a few automatic processes that will delete certain posts after some time has passed).

> This does not have a positive effect on my morale.

Consider **improving** such posts **before** answering them, or if you don't feel they are salvageable, don't answer them.

> I'm here to help other people, and I cannot do that by not answering.

We (Stack Exchange) are here to provide long lasting value - we are trying to get a compendium of good questions and good answers that will be helpful to many people over a long time.

Comment: I don't think _improving_ an unclear question is a good idea. After all, there's no way to know if I even understood the question correctly, so I might just make it worse. Good answer though, thanks.

Comment: @Rawing It's  *hard* enough to find good quality questions to answer that include a MVCE. What your proposing would make it pretty impossible to find them.

Comment: @bluet: Good point.

Comment: @Rawing If there's no way to know if you even understood the question correctly enough to improve it, then you shouldn't be attempting to answer it either. Just close it and let the OP improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Answering is not about helping 1 person.  It is about helping anyone with the same problem.  But in order to help anyone with the same problem, the question needs to be clear, and understandable (while also being on-topic and reasonably scoped).

If the question is missing any of those, it should be closed in order to be a sign post to the original asker that the question needs some maintenance.